# setting transform on UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift, catransform3d

In objective-C I could do:

```
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 200.0);
self.myView.transform = myTransform;
```

So, I am trying t do the same thing in Swift:

```
let myTransform:CGAffineTransform  = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 200.0)
self.myView.transform = myTransform
```

It tells me that UIView does not have a member named "transform"

How can I achieve this in swift?

Comment: Not enough code here.  How is myCode defined.  I'm guessing it's optional.

Comment: correct. Not enough info. Probably though, is to the fact I didn't understand the problem and thought that what I provided was enough. Turns out @Adam is right. So, Thanks for "guessing" to Adam, he's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have declared the `myView` property as `UIView?`. Thats why the compiler complains about it. You can declare it as `UIView`, but then you have to assign it in your class' constructor, or use `!`, like following:

```
self.myView!.transform = myTransform
```

Comment: I did declare my view like so: var myView: UIView? So, I see now what I was doing wrong. I needed to use the "!" operator like @Adam showed here. Thanks

Comment: If you don't ensure `myView` isn't `nil`, you will have a runtime error when you use `myView!`. Use `if myView { myView!.transform = newValue }`